# Mutliple logouts required on Multiple App Servers

Tags: craft-pro

We're using Craft CMS (pro) across multiple application servers and using reddis to manage the sessions.

We're needing to click on 'log-out' twice, sometimes several times before it actually logs us out of the control panel.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your sessions are not being sticky. How many servers?

Are you having to login multiple times as well to get things done?

Apart from what Brad mentioned, couple things I'd try if you haven't already:

- Set an [`appId`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#appId) in the config settings. You didn't mention AWS but setting an appId seems to have [solved it](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/sessions-being-read-inconsistently/9723#9723) for at least one other poster using multiple servers.
- Set [`overridePhpSessionLocation`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#overridePhpSessionLocation) and feed it your redis server (or auto). (It's possible Craft isn't even using Redis if it's not getting set correctly.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that if `overridePhpSessionLocation` is set to `auto`, then Craft is specifically looking for the string `tcp://` in the session save path to determine if it's on some memory based caching environment like Reddis or Memcache.

Comment: I think we resolved the issue. It turned out to be something related to the cache lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the PHP session file isn't being removed from Reddis when you click logout the first time.

The first thing I'd do is, after clicking logout one time, query Reddis to see if that file still exists in memory.  If it does, there is probably some other configuration issue causing it from being deleted.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I didn't have access to our reddis server, but the problem was solved by fixing the cache lifetimes. The techops part of our organization handled it and unfortunately didn't report the exact fix :(